# upload large file to server in android

Tags: php, android

I am not able to upload files to a server which contains spaces in its name. It works fine for files having name without spaces. Here is my code:

```
//this method is invoked when file is selected by file chooser
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
final Intent data) {
if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        File f  = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH));
        String content_type  = getMimeType(f.getPath());


        String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);



        RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("type",content_type)
                .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
                .build();


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url("http://192.168.137.1/cloudserver/save_file.php")
                .post(request_body)
                .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

**php code:**

```
<?php 
    $file_path = "upload/";
    $file_path = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    }else {
        echo "error";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out... I solved my problem by replacing this code

```
String mimeType= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName()); 

RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType),f);`
```